# deep learning/neural network: pre-grouping of Input Variables?

Tags: r, input, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a data set with let's say 100 input variables containing 1000 samples. Each variable represents a price for a product at a different time.

1) I do have the time stamp of that different times. How do can I make use of them?

2) I have additional information for each of those 100 input variables, e.g. whether it is a 'sell' or 'buy' price. Again the question of how to use that information.

So let us say for each of the 100 "input variables", I actually have three information (the 'price' itself, the 'time stamp' and the 'sell/buy'). If I just use all information "next to each other", which would mean having 300 input variables, those additional information is not being used, since it is constant.

Is there any way, that I could have a first Input-Layer, where always three variables lead to one of the 100 Input-variables, which I then could use as an input for a 'common' neural network?

Regards,
Lukas

Comment: You should definitely use the timestamp to properly scale the information. When your time range on your data varies greatly (product 1 has only 10 seconds over all 100 data-points, but product 2 has 20 weeks) the network will become more and more unusable, as it relies on every input having the same meaning in all samples. Maybe you should create a fixed time-interval array of the same length for every product, interpolating between the real data points.